# Django inner join through three tables

Tags: django-models, inner-join

I am trying to inner join three related tables:

```
class Project(models.Model):
   ProjectName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   ProjectCode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.ProjectName

class Center(models.Model):
   CenterName = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
   CenterCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)    
   Project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.CenterName  

class Institute(models.Model):
   InstituteName = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
   InstituteCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
   Center = models.ForeignKey(Center,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.InstituteName
```

I would like to inner join these three modules and filter for center_id.
The query should include ProjectName, ProjectCode, CenterName, CenterCode, InstituteName and InstituteCode.

For now I have in views.py the following lines, which wont deliver all columns I need

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Institute.objects.filter(Center_id=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('InstituteName')
```

How can I retrieve all columns I need (inner join)?

Comment: Hey. No comments at all?
is it that trivial?? and I can't see the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after reading many posts to inner joining tables and lots of try and error I came up with this:

in views.py:

```
class TestInnerJoin(generic.ListView): 
   model = Institute
   template_name = 'Procure/test_inner_join.html'
   queryset = Institute.objects.all().select_related('Center')
```

and in template:

```
{% for qsli in object_list  %}     
   <tr>
     <td>X-{{qsli.Center.Project.ProjectName}}</td>
     <td>{{qsli.Center.Project.ProjectCode}}</td>
     <td>{{qsli.Center.CenterName}}-{{qsli.Center_id}}</td>
     <td>{{qsli.Center.CenterCode}}</td>
     <td>{{qsli.InstituteName}}</td>
     <td>{{qsli.InstituteCode}}</td>
   </tr>          
{% endfor %}
```

It may not be perfect but it solves my problem.

Ben